# I need to make the following directory using two command lines and have to copy the directory using absolute path

Tags: linux, terminal, command, debian

1. Write two command lines needed to create the following directory tree.

```
  ~
  |-- bigboy/
  |   `-- opss/
  |       |-- user
  |       `-- teacher
  |
  `-- arch/
      |-- b/
      |   `-- pr.txt
      |
      `-- 2022F
```

2. Using absolute paths, write one command line to copy directory `opss` with its files to
   directory `2022F`. How do you prove this has been done? Use a second command line and its output to show this has been done as expected.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Use `mkdir` to create directories. You can use the `-p` option to make all the intermediate directories automatically. Use a brace list to create multiple leaf directories.

Comment: You don't need two command lines to make the directories, since you can give multiple arguments to `mkdir`.

Comment: Use the `cp -R` command to copy one directory to another.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)